# How can I show fullscreen image from web using Intent on Android?

Tags: android

Is it possible to show fullscreen image from web using Intent on Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently i use something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/png");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [`ImageView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html),
here is an example:
http://www.androidpeople.com/android-imageview-scaletype-example

You need to use `ScaleType.FIT_XY`

Comment: I don't think that ImageView is the right choice, because it has no controls of Gallary application. I want to create intent that will use Gallery to show fullscreen image